# Get first N array elements from unnest + string_to_array function

Tags: arrays, postgresql, psql

I would like to access first 5 elements of an array "ingredients" before UNNESTing the array:

```
SELECT 
    TRIM
    (REGEXP_REPLACE
        (UNNEST
            (string_to_array(ingredients, ';'))[1:5], '\S+\%|\s+\(.*?\)','','g'))
FROM products
```

The "Ingredients" array may contain values such as:

```
{'1%', 'abc(2%)', 'abcd', ... , N th element}
```

The code below works fine but I don't know what's wrong with the above code.

```
SELECT (string_to_array('1,2,3,4',','))[1:3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
select
  trim(
    regexp_replace(
      unnest(
        (string_to_array(ingredients, ';'))[1:5]
      ),
      '\S+\%|\s+\(.*?\)',
      '',
      'g'
    )
  )
from products;
```

Your example shows how important is to maintain good formatting/indentation.

The following is the same as what you wrote, but re-formatted (opening parenthesis is next to function itself, closing one is at the same indentation level, anything inside is indented more):

```
SELECT 
    TRIM(
        REGEXP_REPLACE(
           UNNEST(
               string_to_array(ingredients, ';')
           )[1:5],
           '\S+\%|\s+\(.*?\)',
           '',
           'g'
        )
    )
FROM products
```

-- the mistake is obvious, you're trying to apply `[1:5]` to an already unnested result set, not to an array.